# My 2GB usb is showing free space-256mb and used space-0 bytes,how to fix it before?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have written a image on the usb by the win32diskimager,before I press write it said that writing to a physical drive may curropt the drive,i thought it may also not corrupt so i pressed write,after finishing my work with the usb,i format it but after formating the usb properties says 'usedspace-0 bytes freespace-256mb',how can a 2 gb flash drive change into 256 mb flash drive.?please help me how can i fix it ?is there any way to make it as like as before again ?

Comment: Maybe someone sold you the wrong thing?

Comment: Related: [How do I fix my USB drive to get its original 8 GB size back?](//superuser.com/q/382242/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive capacity down to 938 MB](//superuser.com/q/752874/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive shows as 16 MB and is unusable](//superuser.com/q/50207/354511), [1 GB space left after formatting a 16 GB flash drive?](//superuser.com/q/339489/354511), [16 GB USB flash drive turned to 1  GB after writing an ISO image onto it](//superuser.com/q/759602/354511), and [Toshiba pen drive shows 4  MB instead of 8  GB; what could have happened to it?](//superuser.com/q/927680/354511)

Answer (score 2):

Use a low level format tool to format the USB disk, here is [one](http://hddguru.com/software/2006.04.12-HDD-Low-Level-Format-Tool/) that might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a low level formatter utility as suggested by @cartman or else boot a Linux system and reformat the flash drive.

The problem you are experiencing is that somehow what you did changed the partitioning and/or the format of the drive. Microsoft has a bad habit of being very self centered in the formats they recognize.  If the drive got repartitioned and or formatted in some strange way that is a non Microsoft supported way, Windows really can't see the extra space.  Linux is much more forgiving - it will be able to see the rest of the drive even if it can't tell what the actual partition/format is.  Under Linux you should be able to repartion/and or reformat it.  A low level format utility - see if your particular drive manufacturer has one on their website - bypasses all of that and goes down to the hardware level and redoes everything in some default format - usually entire drive, FAT32 for compatibility.

Obviously, remember to backup whatever you have on the flash drive because either of these methods is destructive.